# AWT-EventQueue-0 exepction

Tags: java, awt

I'm studying a little example about thread and the program for the example is  follow, the compile well, but when i press the button to start to draw the circle Netbeans throw me an exception, someone could help me.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at feedingschedule.FillDemo.fill(FillDemo.java:63)  at
>   feedingschedule.FillDemo.actionPerformed(FillDemo.java:56)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Thanks.

```
package feedingschedule;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
/**
 *
 * @author ManagerCompufi
 */
public class FillDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  public static final int WIDTH_S = 300;
  public static final int HEIGHT_S = 200;
  public static final int FILL_WITH = 300;
  public static final int FILL_HEIGHT = 100;
  public static final int CIRCLE_SIZE = 10;
  public static final int PAUSE = 100;

  private final JPanel box;  

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   FillDemo gui = new FillDemo();
   gui.setVisible(true);

 }


 public FillDemo(){
   setSize(WIDTH_S, HEIGHT_S);
   setTitle("FillDemo");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   box = new JPanel();

   JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
   buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   JButton startButton = new JButton();
   startButton.addActionListener(this);
   buttonPanel.add(startButton);
   add(buttonPanel, "South");
 }


  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    fill();
  }

  public void fill(){
    Graphics g = box.getGraphics();
      for (int y = 0; y < FILL_HEIGHT; y = y + CIRCLE_SIZE)
        for (int x = 0; x < FILL_WITH; x = x + CIRCLE_SIZE){
        g.fillOval(x, y, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE);
        doNothing(PAUSE);

      }
  }

  public void doNothing(int milliseconds){
    try {
      Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Unexpected interrup");
      System.exit(0);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your program,

```
 Graphics g = box.getGraphics(); // which returns null
```

and afterward , you are try to perform some operation on it,

```
 g.fillOval(x, y, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE); // which leads to NullPointerException
```

So, better to put checks over there likewise,

```
Graphics g = box.getGraphics(); 
if(g != null){
        for (int y = 0; y < FILL_HEIGHT; y = y + CIRCLE_SIZE)
            for (int x = 0; x < FILL_WITH; x = x + CIRCLE_SIZE){
                ......
            }
    }
```